# How to specify tab as a record separator for hadoop input text file?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, inputstream, csv

The input file to my hadoop M/R job is a text file in which the records are separated by tab character '\t' instead of newline '\n'. How can I instruct hadoop to split using the tab character as by default it splits around newlines and each line in the text file is taken as a record.

One way to do it is to use a custom input format class that uses a filter stream to convert all tabs in the original stream to newlines. But this does not look elegant.

Another way would be to use `java.util.Scanner` with tab as the separator. But I cannot figure out how to use the `java.util.Scanner` class in the input format classes.

What is the best approach and alternatives?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you get around this by putting your records on different lines?
As opposed to: record1 \t record2 \t etc..
Using:
record1 \n
record2
That is - if you can control what your input format is.  Otherwise you'll need to change the input format and record reader classes.

Comment: I can't change the input file. It is used by other applications as well.

Comment: Then you will probably have to do what the already posted answer said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values '\r' and '\n' hard-coded in org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader class, so you can't use TextInputFormat with tab-separated records. But it is not difficult to implement own InputFormat with special LineReader class. The simplest solution is to copy-paste TextInputFormat, LineRecordReader and LineReader classes, move them to your package and change LineReader implementation.