# Customer partitioning in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a file in which I have records like `chicken` `10` . I want to partition the data based on   rather than `/t` so that I can get `chicken` as my key and `10` as my value.

I think we need to change the `getPartition` method, but I am not able to do it correctly.

Does anyone has an example of this?

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271641/how-to-specify-tab-as-a-record-separator-for-hadoop-input-text-file

Answer (score 0):

In Streaming the map function reads a line from the STDIO and it's up to the map function (user code) to process it. Here is the sample code for a Python map function

```
import re
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    val = line.strip()
    (year, temp, q) = (val[15:19], val[87:92], val[92:93])
    if (temp != "+9999" and re.match("[01459]", q)):
        print "%s\t%s" % (year, temp)
```